# json encode and canvaschart display not correct in php/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

So many question regarding javascript and so sorry about it. I have create yet a small chart which i promised one of the member/mentor here that I will study real hard in javascript.

So here I am creating a small yet perfect chart but the word perfect seems not fit for it for it returns a wrong display.

Here's the code for the php/html file with the ajax $.getJSON

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.getJSON("data.php", function (result) {

            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                data: [
                    {
                        dataPoints: result
                    }
                ]
            });

            chart.render();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chartContainer" style="width: 800px; height: 380px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now here's the data to be pulled from database

[image]

So there are actually 5 types of dogs based on animal_id
LARGE,MEDIUM,SMALL,PUPPY,DISABLED

Now Here's the data.php

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","siglo");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to DataBase: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}else
{
$data_points = array();

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT animal_id,FROM_UNIXTIME(microtime,' %M ') as microtimes, SUM(srp) as admitting_cost FROM vet_table WHERE microtime BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 180 day)) and 1480723199 GROUP BY telco_id, microtimes");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{        
    $point = array("label" => $row['microtimes'] , "y" =>     $row['admitting_cost'],);
    
    array_push($data_points, $point);        
}

echo json_encode($data_points, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

This is the result
[image]

I can't simply find where I went wrong and the result must be at the bottom is the months and then each month should have 5 bar corresponding to admitting cost

So let's say animal_id 091092010290192(sample) has accumulated 600 on august, 500 on september and  on.....like that

Please help.